# Why location fontawesome icon not working with placeholder?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am using the same technique in both the input field to use font awesome icon in my placeholder. in the case of search, it's working fine but in the case of location, it's not working I have tried changing the CDN link but it's not working.
you can see the below image for more clarity.

**Thanks in advance :-)**

[image: Example form]

```css
.placeholder-icons {
    font-family: fontawesome;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- bootstrap csss -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    
    <!-- custom css -->
</head>
<body>
   <div class="row container">
                                        <div class="col-md-5 p-2">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder-icons" id="skill_input"
                                                placeholder=" &#xf002; SearchSkills, Designations, Companies">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 p-2">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder-icons"
                                                placeholder=" &#xf3c5; Enter Locations">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 p-2">
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem is from this icon only, I tried other icons and it worked.

Comment: which icon is it supposed to be ? Did you check that the unicode you use belongs to the 4.7 version. for example, this , `&#xf14e;` works fine https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icon/compass for map-maker see https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icon/map-marker , it would be `&#xf041` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably used the wrong unicode for 4.7.0 version

try https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icon/map-marker wich would be  `&#xf041` , unicode is  `\f041` if used as a pseudo element.

```css
.placeholder-icons {
  font-family: fontawesome;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- bootstrap csss -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


  <!-- custom css -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-5 p-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder-icons" id="skill_input" placeholder=" &#xf002; SearchSkills, Designations, Companies">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 p-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder-icons" placeholder=" &#xf041; Enter Locations">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 p-2">

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have picked up the Fontawesome code for an icon called map-marker-alt which exists in Fontawesome version 5 but not Fontawesome version 4 which is the one you are loading.

The code f041 gives a map-marker in both versions, albeit they are not exactly the same visually.

Anyway, this snippet gives a location marker I think of the type you were expecting when using version 4:

```css
.placeholder-icons {
    font-family: fontawesome;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- bootstrap csss -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    
    <!-- custom css -->
</head>
<body>
   <div class="row container">
                                        <div class="col-md-5 p-2">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder-icons" id="skill_input"
                                                placeholder=" &#xf002; SearchSkills, Designations, Companies">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 p-2">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder-icons"
                                                placeholder=" &#xf041; Enter Locations">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 p-2">
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                
</body>
</html>
```